# Clearing IE temp files don't erase CRL history. How can this be purged?

Tags: windows, certificates, privacy, public-key-infrastructure

Even after I purge all my Internet temporary files, I still see information when I type

```
 certutil -urlcache
```

How do I purge this information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The information is stored here in Windows 2008 and R2 (Vista and Win7)

```
Per User
C:\Users\username\AppData\LocalLow\ Microsoft\CryptnetUrlCache

Per Computer
C:\Windows\System32\config\ systemprofile\AppData\LocalLow\ Microsoft\CryptnetUrlCache
```

To delete the cached entries run the following command:

```
certutil -urlcache * delete
```